# cannot setup jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm following this example to set up some basic unit testing for a typescript project: https://dev.to/muhajirdev/unit-testing-with-typescript-and-jest-2gln

I have a `main.ts` exporting a `isInternalLink` function

and a `main.spec.ts` that tries to test it

but I get the following error:

```
C:\data\devel\apps\tmp\jest-typescript\src\main.spec.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { isInternalLink } from './main.js';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
```

This is the public repo with the complete example: https://gitlab.com/opensas/jest-typescript

Can anybody point me in the right direction, or provide a working example?

Answer (score 7):

The Jest TypeScript [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript) covers using babel to preprocess the TypeScript files, and also links to `ts-jest`.

To add [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) to your project, install `ts-jest`:

```
npm install --save-dev ts-jest
```

and add this to your package.json to preprocess the TypeScript files:

```
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ]}
```

After doing this in your project I was able to run the tests:

```
$ npx jest
 PASS  src/main.spec.ts
  ✓ should return false given external link (2ms)
  ✓ should return true given internal link

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.096s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was the jest.config.ts fiie, jest only accepts .js or .json config files

Comment: Ha, I missed that you had a transform setup but in wrong file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a demo use `jestjs` with `typescript`: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab

`devDependencies` of `package.json`:

```
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"
```

In the root path of the project, create `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

That's all setup. You can find the documentation and follow the 4 steps here: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#getting-started

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was the jest.config.ts fiie, jest only accepts .js or .json config files

Comment: Not working in my ts react starter,only whit imports with asterisk as before.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my config file was `jest.config.ts`, after trying with:

```
npx jest --config jest.config.ts
Usage: jest.js [--config=<pathToConfigFile>] [TestPathPattern]
[...]
The --config option requires a JSON string literal, or a file path with a .js or .json extension.
Example usage: jest --config ./jest.config.js
```

I just renamed `jest.config.ts` to `jest.config.js` and it went fine...

--

I could solve it with @shadowspan and @slideshowp2 help, thanks!

Comment: it's not a solution